# error, disagreement in macro agreements

Tags: c, mips

I'm attempting to compile a .c file that handles clipping in hardware within the mMIPS instruction set, however I seem to get an error ''Disagreement in number of macro arguments'' at the line ''results=sfu1'' when I try to compile my file with lcc -o mips_mem.bin image.c. I don't understand why it is giving me this error.
This is the image.c:

```
 #define WIDTH   8
 #define HEIGHT  8

 #define sfu0(a, b) ((a) +((b) + *(int *) 0x12344321)) //clipping
 #define sfu1(a, b) ((a) -((b) + *(int *) 0x12344321)) //dividing by 13
 #define sfu2(a, b) ((a) +((b) - *(int *) 0x12344321)) /less multiplications

  void main(void)
 {
int a, b, result;
int max = 255;
char *buf_i = (char*)0x401000, *buf_o = (char*)0x402000;


for (a = 1; a < HEIGHT - 1; a++)
{
    for (b = 1; b < WIDTH - 1; b++)
    {
        result = sfu1((
                     -7*(int)buf_i[(a - 1) * WIDTH + b - 1] +
                      5*(int)buf_i[(a - 1) * WIDTH + b    ] +
                      2*(int)buf_i[(a - 1) * WIDTH + b + 1] +
                     -1*(int)buf_i[ a      * WIDTH + b - 1] +
                     15*(int)buf_i[ a      * WIDTH + b    ] +
                     -1*(int)buf_i[ a      * WIDTH + b + 1] +
                      2*(int)buf_i[(a + 1) * WIDTH + b - 1] +
                      5*(int)buf_i[(a + 1) * WIDTH + b    ] +
                     -7*(int)buf_i[(a + 1) * WIDTH + b + 1] +
                    128));

        /* Clipping */
        buf_o[a * WIDTH + b] = ((result) + ((max) + *(int *) 0x12344321));
    }
}
```

}

Could someone explain what this error means and how it can be fixed?

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sfu1` macro needs 2 arguments, but you only provide one.

This piece of code will result in the same error:

```
result = sfu1(1);
```

Correction:

```
result = sfu1(

               -7 * (int)buf_i[(a - 1) * WIDTH + b - 1] +
               5 * (int)buf_i[(a - 1) * WIDTH + b] +
               2 * (int)buf_i[(a - 1) * WIDTH + b + 1] +
               -1 * (int)buf_i[a      * WIDTH + b - 1] +
               15 * (int)buf_i[a      * WIDTH + b] +
               -1 * (int)buf_i[a      * WIDTH + b + 1] +
               2 * (int)buf_i[(a + 1) * WIDTH + b - 1] +
               5 * (int)buf_i[(a + 1) * WIDTH + b] +
               -7 * (int)buf_i[(a + 1) * WIDTH + b + 1] +
               128

             , 2  // <<<<<<<<< missing argument in your snippet
            );
```

I just added `2` as second argument as an example so your program compiles without error, but it will probably not work. I have no idea what the second argument to those macros should be.

Your code may be incorrect or invokes undefined behaviour, but this is another question.